# How to plot Bode diagrams under scilab / xcos V6.1?

Tags: scilab, xcos

I use scilab / xcos in my teaching and among others the CPGE atoms module: https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/CPGE
This module has not yet been updated for version 6.1 and only works for version 5.5.2.
The majority of its functionalities are found in other modules but one of those which is only found in this module.
The functionality which allows to draw the diagrams of BODE.

Do you know how to find this functionality for version 6 under xcos?

Answer (score 0):

The REP_FREQ block used to do the job, and is still proposed in the CPGE release for Scilab 6.0

Comment: The CPGE module is not offered in the list of ATOMS modules for 6.1.
where did you find it?

Comment: This is why i mention Scilab 6.0.
You may try to access to it from Scilab 6.1 with 

`atomsRepositoryAdd http://atoms.scilab.org/6.0`

before re-running the ATOMS GUI

Comment: Je vais essayer (are you french?)

Comment: I got
=============
atomsRepositoryAdd http://atoms.scilab.org/6.0
 ans  =

   1.

--> atomsInstall("CPGE")
atomsInstallList: The package "CPGE" is not registered.
Please check on the ATOMS repository that it is available for Scilab 6.1 on Windows.
If it is, run atomsSystemUpdate() before trying atomsInstall(..) again.
================

Comment: After having registered the 6.0 repository, you must update your local ATOMS database before running the GUI : atomsSystemUpdate, (or from the GUI : File => Update the list of packages).

Comment: Thanks, that's better, but it still doesn't work. I think it comes from the accounting between iodelay bookstore and CPGE.

Comment: Both CPGE and iodelay are available for Scilab 6.0.
Could you please post the result of atomsGetInstalled()

Comment: No problem for me from Scilab 6.1.0 to install and load CPGE from the 6.0 repository:
```Start iodelay toolbox
 Load macros
 Load help
 Load demos

    Start CPGE - Xcos toolbox
 Load macros
 Load palette - CPGE - Standard blocks
 Load help
 Load demos
 CPGE Version: 1.6.0
```

Comment: Voila
atomsGetInstalled()
 ans  =

  "mingw"     "8.3.0"  "user"  "SCIHOME\atoms\x64\mingw\8.3.0"     "I"
  "SIMM"      "0.6.2"  "user"  "SCIHOME\atoms\x64\SIMM\0.6.2"      "I"
  "coselica"  "0.6.6"  "user"  "SCIHOME\atoms\x64\coselica\0.6.6"  "I"
  "iodelay"   "0.4.7"  "user"  "SCIHOME\atoms\x64\iodelay\0.4.7"   "I"
  "CPGE"      "1.6.3"  "user"  "SCIHOME\atoms\x64\CPGE\1.6.3"      "I"

Comment: but when I run a example with Bode, I got
=================
"Erreur dans post_xcos_simulate : Simulation interrompue."
===============

Comment: Merci pour ton aide